# Knockoutjs operates extremely slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, knockout.js

**In brief**: I've got a page with KO-code that operates absolutely cool in Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. But the performance is gone in Internet Explorer. I tried IE10, IE11. It takes from 10 to 25 seconds to render about 150 rows.
[image]

**Details**: There page represents a work queue for users, where their tasks are shown. The requirement is not to use any paging on that page. Each row of the table has at least a dozen of variants to display (links, buttons, inputs, css styling, handling user events, custom js plugins, etc.). The average number of rows on prod is 100-200+. User is able to apply different filters and sortings.

**Things I've already tried**:

- reduced the number of computed properties (changed to pureComputed, where possible)
- reduced the number of using the *template*, *if* and *ifnot* bindings (according to profiler they are the most time consuming task) - I use the *visible*, where possible
- tried to use the *knockout-fast-foreach* custom binding (https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-fast-foreach)
- profiled the code with IE and Chrome tools to eliminate the memory leaks
- profiled the code with *ko.bindingReport.js* (https://gist.github.com/kamranayub/65399fa247a6c182bc65)

The approaches specifed above tuned the code (according to ***ko.bindingReport.js***) almost two times faster in Chrome. But IE is still too slow - about 10 seconds for rendering.

**Chrome**:
[image: Chrome status]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image: IE status]

Folks, any ideas?

Comment: Which version of KO are you using?

Comment: @f_martinez ko-3.4.0

Comment: Your post is well-written and easy to understand. But if you want to maximize the chance of us being able to help I'm afraid we're going to need a repro. Try to use some bifurcation until you have the root cause and post some example code with test data.

Comment: @Jeroen, I see. But the only thing I've come to - IE is slow on rather elementary update DOM operations. I've minimized the number of computed values to reduce the bindings' update function call. I can't find other bottlenecks on the side of the app. So, I'm not sure, what code samples could help. :(

Comment: @Jeroen, anyway - thanks

Comment: Any short code example that reproduce the problem would suffice. It doesn't have to do anything sensible, as long as it runs without exceptions. Just keep removing application code until you have a short snippet left. (I realize this is often *the* hardest bit of debugging, but apart from guessing at solutions a repro is really probably needed...). At any rate: good luck tracking it down!

Comment: @godspeed - IE11 is known to be terribly slow rendering tables when in Compatibility Mode (IE7 emulation) and there is no dtd (document type declaration)....use the Emulation tab on IE's dev tools (f12) to determine which Emulation Mode (aka documentMode) your development environment is assuming.... it will also tell you how it is being established. eg. x-ua meta, MS Compatibility Lists, Intranet sites, EMSL.
File>Properties dialog will tell you which IE security zone your dev environment maps to... (expected Internet, probable Intranet)

Comment: @RobParsons - Well, document mode is Edge. So, I guess everything is ok from this point of view. Thank you, Rob

Answer (score 1):

"The table binding provides a fast method for displaying tables of data using Knockout. table is about ten times faster than nested foreach bindings."

This claims to be 10x faster.
https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table

Comment: Thanks a lot @idlehands23! For the moment the issue was actual we decided to dynamically render portions of lines as a user scrolls the page. It solved the problem. Next time I will go for knockout-table!

Answer (score 0):

You reduced the amount of computed observables, but did you also reduce the amount of observables? I'm not seeing a lof of editable fields. The ones that are not being edited on the page probably don't need to be an observable? This has boosted my performance quite a lot of times.