# Knockout's foreach taking a long time in IE but faster in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, knockout.js, foreach

I have a 26*26 matrix to be rendered on the UI and then saved into the database. The column labels and the matrix cells are being fetched from the data base in the form of a JSON to render it on the UI using Knockout's foreach. It takes a lot of time for the matrix to get populated in IE (around 5 seconds) but hardly a second in Chrome.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    viewModel=new model(ko,$);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function model(ko,$){
    this.columnLabels=ko.observableArray();
    this.rowData=ko.observableArray();

    this.showMatrix=function(){

        var postData = 'function=fetchColumnsAndMatrix&infodom='+g_infodom+'&matrixType='+this.matrixType()+'&pageMode='+g_pageMode;
        var formURL = 'transMatrix';

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: formURL,
            data: postData,
            aysnc: false,
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR){
                var returnValue=$.trim(responseData);
                returnValue = (eval('('+returnValue+')'));
                viewModel.columnLabels(returnValue["columnLabels"]);
                viewModel.rowData(returnValue["matrices"]);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }
        });

    }
}
```

View:

```html
<table width="100%" id ="transitionMatrix" class="conttablefixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.columnLabels-->
               <th data-bind="text:$data['cellDescription']">
               </th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.rowData">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $root.getColumnLabels($index())"></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: $data-->
            <td class="col12">
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" size="35" class="flegend1" data-bind="value:$data['cellValue']"/>
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:$data['sourceXCoordinate']"/>
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:$data['destYCoordinate']"/>   
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The observables in the viewmodel are mapped to the JSON of these two instances declared in a DTO class.

```
private MatrixDTO [][] matrices; 
private List<MatrixLabels> columnLabels;
```

I am able to get the JSON from the server within a fraction of a second. So it is not an issue with population of 2-d array matrices.

It is working fine for Chrome but not IE. Can some one please tell me what needs to be done for improving the performance in Internet Explorer.

Here is a part of the JSON:

{"matrices":[[{"transitionMatrixDefId":null,"ficMisDate":null,"destYCoordinate":"AAA INT","sourceXCoordinate":"AAA INT","cellValue":null},..........
,{"transitionMatrixDefId":null,"ficMisDate":null,"destYCoordinate":"C INT","sourceXCoordinate":"D INT","cellValue":null},{"transitionMatrixDefId":null,"ficMisDate":null,"destYCoordinate":"C- INT","sourceXCoordinate":"D INT","cellValue":null},{"transitionMatrixDefId":null,"ficMisDate":null,"destYCoordinate":"D INT","sourceXCoordinate":"D INT","cellValue":null}]],"columnLabels":[{"cellValue":"AAA INT","cellDescription":"INT LT Rating AAA"},{"cellValue":"C- INT","cellDescription":"INT LT Rating C-"},{"cellValue":"D INT","cellDescription":"INT LT Rating D"}]}

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603627/knockoutjs-operates-extremely-slow-in-internet-explorer ? There is a mention of the `fast-foreach` that you might want to look at..

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I use fast-foreach. Do I need to add a new js library file. If yes, I may not be allowed to do that.

Comment: I'm afraid we can currently only *guess* at the problem, we'd need a [mcve] that includes sample data to be able to verify answers we'd give. In addition, it would help if you include version numbers for internet explorer and knockoutjs that you're tied to. (Also, in general, if Ajax calls *really* aren't the culprit, it's best to replace that code with stub data anyways so we can more easily help you.)

Comment: So many little things... 1) What do you use `eval()` for? Remove that. jQuery does the JSON parsing for you. 2) String concatenation is *not* how request data is supposed to be built. Pass a JavaScript object as `data`, jQuery will convert the object to the proper format. 3) ` data-bind="value:$data['cellValue']"` is a needlessly complex way of writing `data-bind="value: cellValue"`. 4) You don't really need hidden form fields in a Knockout application. All your data is in the viewmodel, hidden HTML is completely superfluous.

Comment: I have kept the hidden fields so as to make a JSON with those fields when I submit the form.

Comment: Don't "paste the JSON". Make a functional (!)  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demonstrates the issue, just as Jeroen has asked. StackOverflow supports runnable code snippets, alternatively use jsFiddle. If you want people to help you you need to give them working code to investigate.

Comment: I am trying to make a JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/contact_arunabh/r7Lapfde/) but its not working. Any ideas what makes my code to work so fast in Chrome but slow in IE. I am using IE version 11 and knockout-3.1.0.

Comment: Check  your console... You were missing a method in your viewmodel and didn't define `$`. Here's a fixed fork that you can try in IE. The console should log the time it took to render the table. For me, in Chrome, it's 10ms. https://jsfiddle.net/e6n8xa4s/

Comment: The issue is with IE, not Chrome and actually the matrix to be created is 26*26. For simplicity I had shown it 4*4.